# How to always turn off hl-line-mode, i.e., globally

Tags: emacs

I use Cocoa Emacs 23.1.91 and I want to always have hl-line-mode turned off as I don't like using it. I can turn it off per buffer via M-x hl-line-mode, but that is tedious. Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you are having this enabled by the mode (I'm pretty sure you would have to request it explicitly) you can always add this to your .emacs

```
(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook
  (lambda()
    (hl-line-mode -1)
    (global-hl-line-mode -1))
  't
)
```

as the last line of config. `'t` is important as it will tell emacs to append this hook at the end of all hooks for the mode

Comment: You solved it, thanks!!!! If I had the reputation I would give you heaps of points, but the system won't allow me to yet.

Comment: I want to also turn off auto-fill-mode in ruby-mode so I tried:

(add-hook 'ruby-mode-hook
  (lambda()
    (auto-fill-mode -1)
    (hl-line-mode -1)
    (global-hl-line-mode -1))
  't
)

but no dice. The hl-line-mode stuff works as expected, which is great, but I haven't found how to turn off auto fill in ruby-mode. Any ideas?

Comment: This worked for me in Magit + Doom. In particular: `(add-hook 'magit-mode-hook (lambda() (hl-line-mode 0)) 't)` in `config.el`.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to have it always disabled it's probably best to add this line to your .emacs:

```
(global-hl-line-mode -1)
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. As per above, I will check out if I can override this in Ruby mode, as it seems to be possibly coming from there (since I don't have it everywhere). I did add that to my .emacs file though to catch it elsewhere and it seemed to work.

Answer (score 4):

M-x global-hl-line-mode

---

doc:

> global-hl-line-mode is an interactive compiled Lisp function in `hl-line.el'.
>   (global-hl-line-mode &optional ARG)
>
> Global minor mode to highlight the line about point in the current window.
>   With ARG, turn Global-Hl-Line mode on if ARG is positive, off otherwise.
>
> Global-Hl-Line mode uses the functions `global-hl-line-unhighlight' and`
>   global-hl-line-highlight' on `pre-command-hook' and`post-command-hook'.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I could see from the minibuffer message that this function did execute, however, I still have the hl-line. Perhaps it is a feature of the Ruby mode I am using as part of the Emacs Starter Kit set of initializations. I will investigate there about overriding that feature in Ruby mode.

Comment: If invoking it interactively, with M-x, you need to prefix it with `universal-argument`.  I have this bound to C-u .  If putting it in your .emacs, then use `(global-hl-line-mode 0)`.   I updated the answer with the documentation for the fn.